# Change Button image & multiple text programatically

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I need to change the button background image programmatically in Android Activity.

**Scenario Overview:**

User clicks the button in 1st Activity, and it takes user to another 2nd Activity; 
after he return to the 1st Activity, the initial Button image should change based on his actions on 2nd activity.

He again clicks the button and moves to a third activity, and does some actions and return back to first activity and the initial button appears.

Traditional way of setting a button image is this:

```
             <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    style="@style/ButtonText"
                    android:background="@drawable/dynamics"
                    android:text="default"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color" />
```

Also there are some additional dynamic text getting displayed into the button.
For example the Day in Date (in bottom left corner) in the below button:

[image]

And also please check how the Day turns Red during weekends.

this is almost similar to **Apple's calendar button**:

[image: Apple's calendar button]

How I can do the same in Android, especial the dynamic text (changing date) in the button?

**PS: The above 2 images are same button with 3 parts. There are 3 different Text area in the same button**

Comment: button.setText(text);?

Comment: @ElDuderino it is more complex then that. Unlike normal Button, this button will be containing 3 different texts and every time before I draw this button into the screen, I need to refer some Global data to get values of all the 3 texts.

Comment: So you override onDraw()? Then you are doing it probably wrong, what you want to do is build a compound view ... http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-create-compound-controls-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, You want to do two things:

1. Set Button's background image dynamically.
2. Set Button's text dynamically (i.e. from the activity).

You can set the background image of the button as follows:

```
button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon1);
```

And the text of the button can be set as follows:

```
b1.setText("Some text");
```

As far as global data is concerned, you can define your strings as "public static final" in your activity and have a switch case in place, to set the text or images, as needed. Hope this helps.

Comment: Button has multiple texts. How you do that?

Comment: @iKishore Have you set linear or some other layout's property clickable and focusable to achieve this multiple text effect  button??

Comment: I think using [State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) could make your job much easier.

Comment: Actually, the state list defines different states and the drawables to be used in those states, so using it in a custom view would do the trick for you. A custom view extends view class to create custom UI element, like in your image above. Here is a nice [tutorial of custom view.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html)